# How to get the second moment of the gradient

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

In the [OpenAI Five paper](https://cdn.openai.com/dota-2.pdf) it is mentioned that the "Gradients are additionally clipped per parameter to be within between ±5√*v* where *v* is the running estimate of the second moment of the (unclipped) gradient.". This is something I would like to implement in my project, but I am not sure how to do it neihter in theory nor in practice.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) I found out that the "The second central moment is the variance. The positive square root of the variance is the standard deviation [...]". My best guess regarding the "running estimate" is that it is the Exponential Moving Average. The gradients of a network can be accessed as [this comment suggests](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/explicitly-obtain-gradients/4486/2).

From these I would assume that √*v* is the Exponential Running Average of the standard dev. of the gradients and could be calculated via:
`estimate = alpha * torch.std(list(param.grad for param in model.parameters())) + (1-alpha) * estimate`

Is my theory correct? Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: fixed gradient gathering after [Mr. For Example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13509540/mr-for-example)"s answer.

Comment: This question not only related to pytorch, but also related to other more general field like machine learning, I suggest you add more tag on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right path, my guess is basically as same as yours, just with little different.

**First, what is moment?**

N-th moment of a random variable is defined as the expected value of that variable to the power of n. More formally:

[image]

m — moment, X — random variable

So the first moment is mean, and the second moment is **uncentered variance** (meaning we don’t subtract the mean during variance calculation), intuitively, clipping the gradients by moving average of its standard deviation wrt zero make sense.

**Second, what is the correct code?**

`list(network.parameters())` only give you the parameters, for get gradient of each parameters you need `[param.grad for param in network.parameters()]`

Given all the things we know above, the correct code should be (you can try to optimize it by all means):

```
grads_square = torch.FloatTensor([torch.square(param.grad) for param in network.parameters()])
estimate = alpha * torch.sqrt(torch.mean(grads_square)) + (1-alpha) * estimate
```

Comment: Thank you, I intended to get the gradients in exactly the way you advised it to. But i was unable to do it with my "30 minnutes after mindnight" brain. Will edit my question on only that!

Comment: No problem, glad to see good question like this, you have a good day : )

Comment: The more thought I give to your answer the more I think you are right. The `sqrt` in your code seems a bit premature though, as we need to update the `estimate` first and only take the the square root of the updated estimate.

Comment: I just realied that your code is keeping an estimate of √*v* and not *v*, which my intuition suggests is just as good. It is just not in alignment with the notation of the paper. And now I also realized that my question was also not in alignment with it either.

Comment: Well, I thought that is what you want, but you could change it by simply deleted the `torch.sqrt()` in the colde